# Are we undermining ourselves by converting answer-comments to comments?

Tags: discussion

I was reading [What measures have been/can be taken to guide guests & new users with respect to the rep requirement to comment?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9746/what-measures-has-been-can-be-taken-to-guide-guests-new-users-with-respect-to) and I was reminded of what had seemed to be a trend lately of people posting such "Answer-comments" and having them be transformed, and whether it was a good idea.

Specifically, I feel like we may be encouraging people who lack sufficient rep to comment to instead post an answer, knowing that it will be converted for them. On one hand, that seems mildly absurd since anyone who'd read enough of the site to know that we routinely turn such answer-comments into actual comments ought to have, or be able to accrue, sufficient rep to comment. On the other hand, we do have lurkers who may be quite familiar with how we do business, but have never registered an account.

Ultimately, this is not something I see as a huge issue, but it occurs to me from time to time, and now seemed like a good time to bring it up.

Comment: Most times they don't do it twice.

Comment: A lot of them get deleted, too, so the conversion thing isn't a sure go.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**No, we are not undermining ourselves.** We should teach new users how to use the site, not punish them for a minor infraction.

Posting a comment as answer is a common mistake for new users, especially those who have not read the tour page. In our current review system one of the tools when a post is flagged as "Low Quality" is to attach a canned comment to help guide the new user to the tour page.  If you are feeling a more personal mood, you can leave direct comment to assist the new user. However, if the trend continues, further action may be warranted and my time here has shown me that the self-moderation tools provided do a nice job of preventing abuse of the site. If the situation does take a turn for the worse, our ever-vigilant moderators can step in.

I feel this is the correct approach as we should try to welcome new users the best way we can. The problem will work itself out; the new user will either 1) take the advice and become a constructive member of the site or 2) ignore the advice and leave the site. First impression go both ways, so we should strive to show our commitment to helping other and of course *being nice*.

Comment: +1 to this. It's pretty rare for them to do it again and often it's the original OP struggling to get logged back in.

Comment: @armadillo New Meta questions... "Are our moderators Vigilante's?"